# Getting Error for a tag that is not being used in code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This is the Error i'm getting upon running code:

> ERROR in src\index.js

> Line 8:12:  'CssBaseline' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

> webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning

Comment: The line number is pointing `<App />`. Does your app use MaterialUI because that's the problem.

Comment: I **was** using Material UI but i removed it from all the place afterwards, but i'm still getting the Error.

Comment: I just rewrote app.jsx and the issue was resolved.
Thanks for the help.